# How To Get Input From URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I want an input form url.
for example:
this is my website : ***abc.html?name=anyname***
i want **anyname** as input.

i have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
window.onload = function(){

    function ParseURLParameter(Parameter)
    {
        var FullURL=window.location.search.substring(1);
        var ParameterArray=FullURL.split('&');
        for(var i=0; i<ParameterArray.length;i++)
        {   
            var CurrentParameter=ParameterArray[i].split('=');
            if(CurrentParameter[0]==Parameter)
            {
                return CurrentParameter[1];
            }
        }
    }

    var PageName=ParseURLParameter('name');
    if(typeof PageName!=='undefined'){
        if(PageName=='Parameter'){
            alert(PageName);
        }
    }else{
        alert('No Page Parameter Found...');
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: now how can i display the param1 input in html script...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this :**

In variable `name` you can find value of querystring `anyname`

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
        setInterval(function () {
                var name = GetParameterValues('name'); 
                if(name != 'undefined'){
                      $("#lblValue").text(name);
                }
            }, 1000);

        function GetParameterValues(param) {  
            var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
            for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {  
                var urlparam = url[i].split('=');  
                if (urlparam[0] == param) {  
                    return urlparam[1];  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.        but how can i display the input..?

Comment: display means you need to alert it ?

Comment: you are saying that, i can find the value of querystring `anyname` in variable `name`.
but i am continuously try to displaying the variable `name` value in html file.
but still i am not succesfull yet.
please now tell me only that how can i display...?
Thanks

Comment: @M.U.F.Azmi Please see my updated answer. It does make sense ?