# Query string in .html extension files

Tags: php, html, web, server

For some sites that have their backend on PHP/any other server side languages, the query string `http://example.com/?param1=whatever` makes sense. But I saw it is used with pages that have `.html` extension as well. How does that make sense? If we are explicitly writing the url to end in `.html`, it means it is referring to a file located on the server, and it is an `HTML` file, which cannot deal with server side stuff. So how does it make sense?

As an example, `http://www.example.com/mypage.html?crcat=test&crsource=test&crkw=buy-a-lot1`, this url is given on https://help.marketruler.com/wiki/What_is_the_correct_syntax_for_query_strings%3F link (under Landings to a page within your domain name with no query string).

Comment: check out this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47653447/6715678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. You can fetch the parameters with JavaScript and use them with client side programming
2. You can change the Mime type of .html files and parse them as a PHP or other programming language script. For example in Apache to make html files to work like php scripts it is as simple as adding this to .htaccess file:

   AddType application/x-httpd-php .html